# Entity Framework tables not created (Code first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I tried to use code first for the first time after always having used DBfirst but for some reason it does not create my tables when I run my project and I am clueless what I am missing even after reading many stackoverflow posts.

I have the following code:

Class.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EdulySoft.Models
{
    public partial class Class
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ClassRoomId { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public int MaxStudents { get; set; }

        public virtual Classroom classrooms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

classroom.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EdulySoft.Models
{
    public partial class Classroom
    {
        public Classroom()
        {
            this.classes = new HashSet<Class>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ClassRoomName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Class> classes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SchoolContext

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EdulySoft.Models
{
    public class schoolContext : DbContext
    {

        public schoolContext() : base()
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using EdulySoft.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EdulySoft
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var ctx = new schoolContext())
            {
                Class stud = new Class() { Id = 1, ClassName = "Loquat", MaxStudents = 12, ClassRoomId = 1 };

                ctx.Classes.Add(stud);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

App.config

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="EdulySoft.Properties.Settings.schoolContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Eduly;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I used an empty console app to start with. Any help will be much appreciated. Cheer!

Comment: Did you create a migration and updated the database?

Comment: I haven't created a migration yet, is that necessary for creating the database?

Comment: Yes. After your changes you need to go to the Package manager console and type "Add-Migration your-migration-name". You will see the code of the created migration and then you can type "update-database" in the console. This should update your database. However make sure you have your EF-Project selected under "Default project" in the console.

Comment: Your connection string name in app config is EdulySoft.Properties.Settings.schoolConnectionString which should be schoolContext

Comment: I made both changes but still nothing gets created. The migrations says that the database ran and even did the seed method. but still I got no tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are looking at the correct data source in SQL Management Studio. In the connection string it is:

> (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

.

Comment: Yes I was in (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB, but for some reason it created it onder \SQLEXPRESS. I am clueless why it did that since I specified (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB. Anyways thanks for letting me check it as I now found my database. Cheers